# Confusing GCP Cloud SQL Query Insights Chart

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How do I read this GCP Cloud SQL - Query Insights chart?

There are two Y-axes.

The left one seems to show the total CPU capacity. What is the right one - is that the `CPU and CPU Wait`?

Also, how do I reconcile this peak:

- The CPU capacity is shown at 2 (the maximum)
- The peak though goes above the line of 2
- But the CPU and CPI wait are just `0.449`

[image: GCP Cloud SQL Query Insights Chart]

Comment: "The peak though goes above the line of 2"  No, it just barely misses reaching 1.  You are looking at the wrong axis.

Comment: @Mike Borozdin Let me know if below suggestion helped? or you are looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

As @jjanes mentioned above it might be possible that you are looking at the wrong axis. And to answer your specific questions I have given my inputs below. I hope those helps.

> How do I read this GCP Cloud SQL - Query Insights chart?

I hope you are looking for a definition of the terms involved in the graph. As stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-query-insights#using-db-load-graph),

> Colored lines in the graph show the query load, split into four
> categories:
>
> - **CPU capacity**: The number of CPUs available on the instance.
> - **CPU and CPU Wait**: The ratio of the time taken by queries in an active state to wall-clock time. IO and Lock waits don't block queries
>   that are in an active state. This metric might mean that the query is
>   either using the CPU or waiting for the Linux scheduler to schedule
>   the server process running the query while other processes are using
>   the CPU.
> - **IO Wait**: The ratio of time taken by queries that are waiting for IO to wall-clock time. IO wait includes Read IO Wait and Write IO
>   Wait. See the PostgreSQL [event
>   table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#WAIT-EVENT-TABLE).
>   If you want a breakdown of information for IO waits, you can see it in
>   Cloud Monitoring. See [Cloud SQL
>   metrics](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/metrics)
>   for more information.
> - **Lock Wait**: The ratio of time taken by queries that are waiting for Locks to wall-clock time. It includes Lock Waits, LwLock Waits,
>   and Buffer pin Lock waits. To see a breakdown of information for lock
>   waits, use Cloud Monitoring. See [Cloud SQL
>   metrics](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/metrics)
>   for more information.

> What is the right one - is that the CPU and CPU Wait?

Yes, Seems it is indicating CPU and CPU Wait.

> Also, how do I reconcile this peak? `The peak though goes above the line of 2`

check the below Note section: As per Note in [Document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-query-insights#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20CPU%20load%20accounts%20for%20both%20the%20runtime%20and%20the%20time%20waiting%20for%20the%20Linux%20scheduler%20to%20schedule%20the%20server%20process%20that%27s%20running.%20As%20a%20result%2C%20the%20CPU%20load%20can%20go%20beyond%20the%20maximum%20core%20line)

`Note: CPU load accounts for both the runtime and the time waiting for the Linux scheduler to schedule the server process that's running. As a result, the CPU load can go beyond the maximum core line.`

It seems it is an intended behavior.